# When reviewing close votes, what should happen to low-effort questions that don't match any close reason?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074741/sorry-game-in-java-issue) when reviewing close votes. "X, Y and Z happen. They aren't supposed to happen. Here's my code." The given close reason was "too broad".

This question seems to be low effort (no attempt at debugging is shown), doesn't contribute to Stack Overflow's goal of building a repository of programming knowledge, and doesn't match any valid close reason.

What is the appropriate review action here? Voting to leave the question open seems wrong, because it's not a good question. Voting to close the question is definitely wrong. I don't see any way the question could be edited to improve it, either.

Comment: You are looking for the "Stack Overflow is not a code debugging service" close reason. It is conspicuously absent. Do exercise your ability to downvote.

Comment: Without tools like that close reason, Stack Overflow *is* a code debugging service, intended or not.

Comment: @Cody What about Other?

Comment: @immiis And, that is fine.  If we don't think the person has taken the effort to try to debug it on their own, we can downvote and ignore.  If we do think he has taken that effort, and is just stuck, then the question is square in the middle of what stack exchange is for.

Comment: @bjb568 the way I see it, "Other" closes should be rare - if it was okay to close a question for that reason, it would be a pre-set close reason!

Comment: Can't post this as a proper answer, but: Low-effort question which is still specific, in-scope, not a dupe etc -> just downvote it. Or better yet: Leave a comment suggesting that OP invest the effort , and only if you see other people's comments to the same effect with no response by OP, then downvote.

Comment: @einpoklum This question specifically mentions close vote reviews.

Comment: @immibis: Yes, but some people vote to close questions simply because they're bad.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a huge code dump with not enough information to narrow down where the problem is/lacks information about the exact error given/would require access to data not provided to replicate the error, I use:

> Off Topic --> "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem."

If there is something obviously wrong in the code from five seconds scanning, I may comment, and close using:

> Off Topic --> "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

If it's a huge code dump which technically one could debug/answer as is but doing so seems counter-productive due to lack of effort from OP/usefulness to future visitors, I just downvote (I may also downvote the closeable ones depending on how bad they are).

In any of the above cases I sometimes drop a link to the relevant debugging tools/help pages in the probably vain hope that the OP will learn to fish.

Comment: "If it's a huge code dump" I close as unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's fine to leave the question open.  It's hardly "too broad" since it's very specific to the asker's code.